# golang-migrate unable to find postgres driver

Tags: postgresql, go, golang-migrate

In my `internal/platform/database/database.go`

```golang
import (
    "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func RunMigrations() error {
    m, err := migrate.New(
        "file://schema",
        "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "error creating migrations object")
    }
```

This function is invoked from my `cmd/my-api/main.go` as follows:

```golang
import (
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/database/postgres"
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/source/file"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/myrepo/myproject/internal/platform/database"
)

    // =========================================================================
    // Executing migrations
    if err := database.RunMigrations(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Although I am importing `postgres` driver in **both** files, `_ "github.com/lib/pq"`

running the program fails as follows:

```
error creating migrations object: source driver: unknown driver file (forgotten import?)
exit status 1
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that `golang-migrate` needs its own version of the corresponding driver (?)

The following import solved it for me

```
_ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/database/postgres"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you import the following, postgres driver init function triggered and this function register the postgres driver.

```
_ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/database/postgres"
```

You can inspect this.
https://www.calhoun.io/why-we-import-sql-drivers-with-the-blank-identifier/